# What is the fastest path to the blue gun?

Tags: antichamber

If I reseted my save of Antichamber, I am not sure I would easily find the blue gun again.

[image]

What is the fastest path to the blue gun, starting from the beginning room?

[image: The beginning of the game]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Start at 'Jump', fall down to bottom.
2. Rush forward into the black tunnel. Ignore the white lines on the floor, go straight ahead. The only directions you get are the white circles that you see if you turn around. Follow this tunnel to where it turns red.
3. When the left part of the tunnel turns red, go right, there is a location switching window here. Look through it and you should be at the blue gun.

The first twenty seconds of

show the path.